# Converting date using awk

Tags: unix

I have a file dates.csv with data like this:

```
Mar 27 2014~Aug 24 2014~Apr 06 2014~
```

I have been trying to convert it into a timestamp and have been unsuccessful at all attempts.

I tried this code:-

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
j=`head -1 dates2| tr '~' '\n' | wc -l`
echo $i
echo $j

while [ $i -lt $j ]
do
    k=`awk 'BEGIN{FS="~"}{print $(i+1)}' dates2`
    echo $k
    date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" -d "$k"
    (( i++ ))
done
```

The awk command is always executing for print $1, I am trying to get it iterated for all the columns that are separated by `FS="~"`.

My desired output is:

```
03/24/2014 00:00:00~08/24/2014 00:00:00~04/06/2014 00:00:00~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, read the dates into an array:

```
$ IFS='~' read -ra dates < file
```

Then loop through the array and convert each one, appending it to a new string:

```
$ converted=""
$ for d in "${dates[@]}"; do 
    converted+=$(date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S~") -d "$d"
done
```

Now `$converted` contains this string:

```
$ echo "$converted"
03/27/2014 00:00:00~08/24/2014 00:00:00~04/06/2014 00:00:00~
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `while` and it worked:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read data
do
   fDate=`date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" -d "$data"`
   echo "new Date: $fDate"
done < dates2
```